# Returning new Laravel model ID before saving

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've seen similar questions for other frameworks but I cant seem to find an answer for Laravel.

What is the best practise / cleanest solutions to achieve my goal.

At the moment lets say I have a model called `Site`.

My site model has a column called `prefix` which is just a few capital letters generated by the site name plus the new site id so for example, row 1 with a site name of 'clare' becomes 'CLA1' and 'pencet' becomes 'PEN2'.

My issue is that I need the new row `id` to generate the prefix, which means at the moment I have to save it, then re-save it like so.

```
$site = new Sites;
$site->name = 'clare';
$site->save();
//Now that we have saved, we can use the new id to create the prefix and save again
$site->prefix = strtoupper(substr($site, 0, 3)) . $site->id;
$site->save();
```

I hate the fact I have to re-save it again once its initially been saved because I need the id, what is the best way to achieve this goal? Is it possible to return the new model ID before it saves?

I know I can do stuff like get a count of all of the rows and get the ID that way instead, but i'm generally looking for the best, cleanest solutions to achieve this.

Comment: Do you need this saved in the database? What's that column for? Can't you use a custom attribute/accessor that dynamically returns the prefix?

Comment: You can't get `id` just before you save your data.. And if you take  `id` from `table` with ` descending order` you can get last `id`, and this is not good either as some records might have been deleted already. So I hope this is the only solution if you really need `id`.

Comment: Why don't you define a prefix method on the model and generate the prefix every time you need it?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan How do we define a prefix method on a model?

Comment: @Tribunal See my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution :

Sites model :

```
public function getNextId() 
{

     $statement = DB::select("show table status like 'sites'");

     return $statement[0]->Auto_increment;
}
```

Note: Do not forget to import DB with 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB';

In the controller :

```
$site = new Sites;
$site->name = 'clare';
$site->prefix = strtoupper(substr($site->name, 0, 3)) . $site->getNextId();
$site->save();
```

Comment: for this solution need add insert block for table

Comment: I didn't get what you mean ! what insert block @J.Doe

Comment: table lock https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: I didn't even know 'show table status' mysql command existed! You learn something new every day. This seems like a nice clean way to do it, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure you will need the insert block as you said @J.Doe let S_R test it :)

Comment: This solution works great for me! Simply calling it like `strtoupper(substr($site, 0, 3)) . (new Sites)->getNextId();` before saving, works great and is nice and clean. Thanks!

Comment: @Maraboc It depends on how many sites are generated per second. Personally, I wouldn't use this strategy because something could happen between you checking the next available ID and saving it. This is why J. Doe suggests locking the table, checking the next available id, saving the new site with it's generated prefix and then unlocking the table again.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I can't imagine there being more than 1 site per minute or so, so I can't picture this being an issue, but please feel free to explain how this is done any way for future reference, that would be great!

Comment: it fails on pgsql

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming some things in my answer, like the fact that you will never use the prefix to define a relationship or identify the site. This should always be done with the ID.

I would suggest using a property and a method in the Sites class to retrieve the `prefix`:

```
private $generatedPrefix = null;

public function getPrefixAttribute() {
    if ($this->generatedPrefix === null) {
        $this->generatedPrefix = strtoupper(substr($this->site, 0, 3)) . $this->id;
    return $this->generatedPrefix;
}
```

By doing it this way, you can access it by using the following code:

```
$site->prefix
```

The same logic as you want, but generated on the fly.

Comment: But will `$site->prefix` return the correct prefix and id before the site itself has been saved?

Comment: No it won't, but it will right after you have saved it. Is there a reason you want it saved to the database?

Comment: Because the whole site row has to be saved, but one of the site fields needs to be the prefix which contains its own ID. So I need to be able to get the new ID before the site is saved to use it inside one of its own fields.

Comment: @S_R Yes, I got that part, but what are you using the prefix for? What is the exact reason you want to store it in the database?

Comment: It is requested by the user of the application as they use the prefix for things like invoices and bills.

Comment: @S_R Ah okay! As for me, I won't deem it necessary to save it to a database, as you can always generate it like I have done. But if you want to save it to the database, that's no problem :)

Comment: Sorry, i've only just clicked on to what you we're getting at! You were saying to always generate the prefix on the fly when i need it instead of storing it somewhere (its early where I am, and I haven't had enough coffee yet). Yes unfortunately its a requirement that its stored, but thank you for your suggestion anyway! :)

Answer (score -1):

How I do it is something like this ..

So I have a model

I define the

```
protected $fillable = []
```

array with the fields that can be mass filled.

Now I need a array with data and mass create :

```
    $newRow  = Page::create($data);
    if($newRow) {
        return Page::find($newRow->id);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

So when the creation is success , I get the whole record back, otherwise false.

Of course this is implemented in a function within the model. So you need to call it from the controller or somewhere else :)

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the question

Comment: Well .. the answer is partly in there .. 

He can also do before the return 

`

$newRow->prefix = "bla bla " . $newRow->id;
$newRow->save();

return Page::find($newRow->id);
`

Comment: He already got this part figured out. The problem or challenge he encounters is doing two queries instead of a single one, which is what he prefers...

Comment: Hmm I see .. well .. good luck then .. would not recommend that strategy. But I am curious of the solution.